# Start a new Activity and get its result, through a non Activity class

Tags: android

Usually, in order to launch a new Activity and get its result, from an Activity class, I will use

***[public void startActivityForResult (Intent intent, int requestCode)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)***

However, what if I try to launch a new Activity and get its result, from a non-Activity class? How I can achieve this?

The reason I ask so as I am currently having `LoginManager` class (A non-Activity class). It is having the following code.

```
    accountManager.getAccountManager().getAuthToken(account, AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE, true, new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {
        public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future) {
            try {
                Bundle bundle = future.getResult();
                if (bundle.containsKey(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT)) {
                    Intent intent = bundle.getParcelable(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT);
                    intent.setFlags(intent.getFlags() & ~Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    // Compilation error, as LoginManager doesn't have startActivityForResult method.
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_AUTHENTICATE);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`((Activity) mContext).startActivityForResult(.....)` will do the trick.

**But results will be delivered to the actual activity holding the context.**

You can apply following Approach

Create single argument constructor in LoginManager class like follows.

```
class LoginManager
{
  private Context mContext; 
  LoginManager(Context mContext)
  {
    this.mContext=mContext;
  }
  .............................
  //Then whenever you want to call method call like this.

  ((Activity) mContext).startActivityForResult(.....)

}
```

Now in Activity class whenever you will create Object of  LoginManager class create as follows.

```
LoginManager loginManager=new LoginManager(ActivityName.this);
```

Comment: Possible do without using context? as login manager do not have access to context.

Comment: You need to have activity Context otherwise you can not use it!

Comment: and you can create a single argument constructor in LoginManager class that accepts activity context!see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

I would have the Activities within your project extend some kind of a "BaseActivity". Within that base activity, I would override onActivityResult() and pass the result into the LoginManager from there.

This will have the consequence of making all of your Activities pass their results to your LoginManager, so you won't have to keep overriding onActivityResult manually everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could just send a reference to your `Context` into the `LoginManager` class and use it to start the `Activity`?

Comment: I think he's looking how to get the activity result into the LoginManager. He can already start the Activity from within the login manager, but cannot get the result when that Activity exits.